# iOS - put custom UIView in a View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

My iOS app has a root view controller, and I want to add a few custom `UIView` to it in runtime. I call these custom views widgets because they are small and basically pretty same except size, label text etc.

I have created .h and .m for my widgets, and .xib file. In my root view controller `viewDidLoad` I do this:

```
TestMyView *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestMyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];    
[self.view addSubview: cell];
```

It works fine. However, I still can't figure out:

- why there's exception `"[<TestViewController 0x7517210> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mylabel"` if I add `UILabel` mylabel as IBOutlet to my custom UIView class .h file. (I drag drop UILabel in IB then control-drag to .h) I need to change label text when view is created. And I dont quite understand why it complains TestViewController while I didn't add IBOutlet to it, but my custom view .h class?
- how do I change label text in right way then. I dont want to create a View controller for my widgets because I think it wouldn't be necessary. I need to create like 5-6 widgets so I need to create 5-6 view controllers for them?
- it seems initWithCoder doesnt get called when I create the widget? I saw apple doc library says if load view from nib file this method will get called.

If you think I suck at explain this, here's my project code:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43017476/custom.tar.gz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.  A few notes.

1st - when you load the view from the nip, the "owner" is the class which has the properties (IBOutlets) references by the nib.  That will probably be an instance of TestMyView.  Usually, create the custom view and let it load it's own nib (as illustrated below).

2nd - loadNibNamed returns an NSARRAY, not a UIVIEW; so you'll want to pull your view out of the array.

Here's an example of creating your custom view (widget):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(nextLeft, nextTop, tileWidth, tileHeight);
TestMyView *widget = [[TestMyView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andFoo:foo];
[widget setWidgetTappedBlock:^{
    // handle tap for this widget
}];
[self.widgetContainerView addSubview:widget];
```

This is part of your custom views implemenatation:

```
@implementation TestMyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andFoo:(Foo *)foo
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        NSArray *nibObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestMyView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0]];
        // More initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And the interface:

```
@interface ProductTileView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, copy) ProductTappedBlock widgetTappedBlock;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andFoo:(Foo *)foo;

@end
```

**Edit:**
PS In your example, the error is caused because the owner sent to loadNib is 'self', which is your view controller.  Your view controller doesn't have the 'myLabel' property, your custom view does.

Comment: 1st point is correct and it could be a problem. But for a 2nd one, I have a question. When we create a view in xib, why do we need to set a frame again in code anyway? And also when we pull out the view from nsbundle array views, we need to type cast I think. +1

Comment: You could create a view in IB and assign your custom class to it.  However, @Lukas is creating 'widget' views dynamically and will almost certainly be placing them on the screen programmatically.  In other situations, you may not need to set the frame.  The NSArray holds NSObjects; and UIView is an NSObject (subclass).  I don't believe lack of cast will generate warning or degrades readability, but certainly will not hurt anything.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by widget views in ios.

Comment: The question's author is referring to his custom views as "widget" that's all.  The answer is tailored for him.  Others can tweak to fit their needs.

Comment: @R.A He means in my question I call custom UIVIEW as "widget". not a term in ios or xcode.

Comment: Oh my god it is just a view act like a template to create many in many places. That's it, Now got it..

Comment: @Dave perfect answer, thanks! Another small question, do you think this is good practice: make view controller for each widget and load all controllers in root controller, OR in root view controller just load all widgets using your example - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andFoo:(Foo *)foo

Comment: Thanks. Depends on the complexity of your 'widgets'.  If you are just showing stats (charts, clocks, weather, etc.) you're all set.  If widgets are more interactive, you'll probably end up making a 'controller' for each widget, however it doesn't need to be a 'view controller', just the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to initiate them befor adding to your rootView!

```
TestMyView *cell = [[TestMyView alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestMyView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview: cell];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but TestMyView is subclass of UIView, not UIViewController, so initWithNibName is not for it..